# How can I move centralWidget to the top left conner?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm building an image viewer program using PyQt5, but encounter a problem.
When I open an image file, it locates at the middle of main window. I checked the position of mouse cursor, the top left corner of the image is not (0,0). However, what I want to do is locating the top left corner of the image at (0,0). In order to do that, I have to fit the image to window. Please let me know the fine solution

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, \
    QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QMenu, QWidget, QToolBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QGroupBox, QBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import cv2
from image_trans import HistoEqual
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
#? from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
global image_type
image_type = 1 #0:original, 1:equlaization

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):

        self.createActions() 
        self.createMenus() 
        self.createToolbar()
        
        self.image_frame = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.image_frame)                    
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')
        self.resize(500, 350)
        self.center()
        self.show()
    
    def createActions(self):
        self.openAct = QAction("&Open...", self, shortcut = "Ctrl+O", triggered=self.open)
        self.exitAct = QAction("Exit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close)
    
    def createMenus(self):
        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct) 
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.fileMenu)

    def createToolbar(self):
        self.toolbar1 = self.addToolBar('image convert')

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('Original')
        self.btn1.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.img_original)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Equlaization')
        self.btn2.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.img_equlaizataion)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.btn3 = QPushButton('canny')
        self.btn3.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.img_canny)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn3)

        self.spinbox1 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox1.setRange(1,10)
        self.spinbox1.setValue(5)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.spinbox1)
        self.spinbox2 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox2.setRange(0,256)
        self.spinbox2.setValue(1)
        self.spinbox2.valueChanged.connect(self.img_canny)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.spinbox2)
        self.spinbox3 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox3.setRange(0,256)
        self.spinbox3.setValue(1)
        self.spinbox3.valueChanged.connect(self.img_canny)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.spinbox3)

        self.btn4 = QPushButton('Original')
        self.btn1.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.img_original)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn4)

        ###################3 나중에 사용
        grp_1 = QGroupBox()
        grp_1_layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
        grp_1.setLayout(grp_1_layout)


    def img_original(self): 
        height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img.shape 
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImg = QImage(
            self.img, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bytesPerLine, 
            QImage.Format_RGB888
        )
        A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  
        
    def img_equlaizataion(self):
        self.img_equal = HistoEqual(self.img)
        height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img_equal.shape 
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImg = QImage(
            self.img_equal, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bytesPerLine, 
            QImage.Format_RGB888
        )
        A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  

    def img_canny(self):
        thresh1 = self.spinbox2.value()
        thresh2 = self.spinbox3.value()
        self.img_canny = HistoEqual(self.img)
        self.img_canny = cv2.medianBlur(self.img_canny, 5)
        # self.img_canny = cv2.GaussianBlur(self.img, (11,11), 0)
        # self.img_canny = HistoEqual(self.img_canny)
        
        self.img_canny = cv2.Canny(self.img_canny, thresh1, thresh2)
        self.img_canny = cv2.cvtColor(self.img_canny, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img_canny.shape 
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImg = QImage(
            self.img_canny, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bytesPerLine, 
            QImage.Format_RGB888
        )
        A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(A) 

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry() 
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center() 
        qr.moveCenter(cp) 
        self.move(qr.topLeft()) 
    
    def open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()', 
            '',
            'Images (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)', 
            options=options
        )

        if fileName:
            self.sid = QImage(fileName)
            self.src_raw = self.qimg2cv(self.sid)           
            self.src = self.src_raw.copy()
            self.img = self.src.copy() 
            # self.show_image(self.img)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            # ! 2            
            height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img.shape
            bytesPerLine = 3 * width
            # cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, self.img)
            QImg = QImage(
                self.img.data, 
                width, 
                height, 
                bytesPerLine, 
                QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
            # self.show_image(self.pixmap)
            
            self.image_frame.setPixmap(self.pixmap)                              # ! 3           
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
    
    def qimg2cv(self, q_img):                           
        q_img.save('temp_.png', 'png')
        mat = cv2.imread('temp_.png')                 
        return mat

    def show_image(self, A):
        if image_type == 0:
            A = self.pixmap
            self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  
        elif image_type == 1:
            A = self.qimg2cv(A)
            A = HistoEqual(A)
            height, width, bytesPerComponent = A.shape 
            bytesPerLine = 3 * width
            QImg = QImage(
                A, 
                width, 
                height, 
                bytesPerLine, 
                QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
            self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  

    def getPos(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y() 
        print(x,',',y)
    
    def mouseButtonKind(self, buttons):
        if buttons & Qt.LeftButton:
            print("left")
        
        if buttons & Qt.RightButton:
            print("right")
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("button press")
        x = event.x() 
        y = event.y()
        print(x,",",y)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('button release') 
        x = event.x() 
        y = event.y()
        print(x,",",y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bool QLayout::setAlignment(QWidget *w, Qt::Alignment alignment)
>
> Sets the alignment for widget w to alignment and returns true if w is found in this layout (not including child layouts); otherwise returns false.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, \
    QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QMenu, QWidget, QToolBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QGroupBox, QBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import cv2

# ??? from image_trans import HistoEqual

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
#? from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
global image_type
image_type = 1 #0:original, 1:equlaization

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):

        self.createActions() 
        self.createMenus() 
        self.createToolbar()
        
        self.image_frame = QLabel()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
#        self.setCentralWidget(self.image_frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.image_frame, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)          # ! Qt.AlignTop
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')
        self.resize(500, 350)
        self.center()
        self.show()
    
    def createActions(self):
        self.openAct = QAction("&Open...", self, shortcut = "Ctrl+O", triggered=self.open)
        self.exitAct = QAction("Exit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close)
    
    def createMenus(self):
        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct) 
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.fileMenu)

    def createToolbar(self):
        self.toolbar1 = self.addToolBar('image convert')

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('Original')
        self.btn1.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.img_original)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Equlaization')
        self.btn2.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.img_equlaizataion)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.btn3 = QPushButton('canny')
        self.btn3.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.img_canny)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn3)

        self.spinbox1 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox1.setRange(1,10)
        self.spinbox1.setValue(5)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.spinbox1)
        self.spinbox2 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox2.setRange(0,256)
        self.spinbox2.setValue(1)
        self.spinbox2.valueChanged.connect(self.img_canny)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.spinbox2)
        self.spinbox3 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox3.setRange(0,256)
        self.spinbox3.setValue(1)
        self.spinbox3.valueChanged.connect(self.img_canny)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.spinbox3)

        self.btn4 = QPushButton('Original')
        self.btn1.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.img_original)
        self.toolbar1.addWidget(self.btn4)

        ###################3 나중에 사용
        grp_1 = QGroupBox()
        grp_1_layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
        grp_1.setLayout(grp_1_layout)


    def img_original(self): 
        height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img.shape 
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImg = QImage(
            self.img, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bytesPerLine, 
            QImage.Format_RGB888
        )
        A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  
        
    def img_equlaizataion(self):
        self.img_equal = HistoEqual(self.img)
        height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img_equal.shape 
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImg = QImage(
            self.img_equal, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bytesPerLine, 
            QImage.Format_RGB888
        )
        A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  

    def img_canny(self):
        thresh1 = self.spinbox2.value()
        thresh2 = self.spinbox3.value()
        self.img_canny = HistoEqual(self.img)
        self.img_canny = cv2.medianBlur(self.img_canny, 5)
        # self.img_canny = cv2.GaussianBlur(self.img, (11,11), 0)
        # self.img_canny = HistoEqual(self.img_canny)
        
        self.img_canny = cv2.Canny(self.img_canny, thresh1, thresh2)
        self.img_canny = cv2.cvtColor(self.img_canny, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img_canny.shape 
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImg = QImage(
            self.img_canny, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bytesPerLine, 
            QImage.Format_RGB888
        )
        A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(A) 

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry() 
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center() 
        qr.moveCenter(cp) 
        self.move(qr.topLeft()) 
    
    def open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()', 
            '',
            'Images (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)', 
            options=options
        )

        if fileName:
            self.sid = QImage(fileName)
            self.src_raw = self.qimg2cv(self.sid)           
            self.src = self.src_raw.copy()
            self.img = self.src.copy() 
            # self.show_image(self.img)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            # ! 2            
            height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img.shape
            bytesPerLine = 3 * width
            # cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, self.img)
            QImg = QImage(
                self.img.data, 
                width, 
                height, 
                bytesPerLine, 
                QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
            # self.show_image(self.pixmap)
            
            self.image_frame.setPixmap(self.pixmap)                              # ! 3           
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
    
    def qimg2cv(self, q_img):                           
        q_img.save('temp_.png', 'png')
        mat = cv2.imread('temp_.png')                 
        return mat

    def show_image(self, A):
        if image_type == 0:
            A = self.pixmap
            self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  
        elif image_type == 1:
            A = self.qimg2cv(A)
            A = HistoEqual(A)
            height, width, bytesPerComponent = A.shape 
            bytesPerLine = 3 * width
            QImg = QImage(
                A, 
                width, 
                height, 
                bytesPerLine, 
                QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            A = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
            self.image_frame.setPixmap(A)  

    def getPos(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y() 
        print(x,',',y)
    
    def mouseButtonKind(self, buttons):
        if buttons & Qt.LeftButton:
            print("left")
        
        if buttons & Qt.RightButton:
            print("right")
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("button press")
        x = event.x() 
        y = event.y()
        print(x,",",y)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('button release') 
        x = event.x() 
        y = event.y()
        print(x,",",y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: It's you again! thank you for kind and fine solution!